# Place order button is missing in the checkout

Tags: magento2, cart, onepage-checkout, place-order

I don't know how did that happened but I'm using onepagecheckout

Website: https://femascu.net/

Product to add to cart: https://femascu.net/femascu-leather-watch-8401.html

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have verified your one-page checkout page HTML code by Inspect Element and found that one of the Checkout Page CSS showing or set as **"Display: none"**.

You can check the below screenshot for your reference.
[image]

You can resolve this issue by following steps.

```
1] Removing or commenting on the below CSS class code from the checkout CSS file.

CSS File Path : https://femascu.net/static/_cache/merged/1784163dac242cad636193ba20c62a2e.css

#checkout-payment-method-load .payment-method-content .actions-toolbar .primary .action.checkout {
  display: none;
}

2] Modifying the below CSS class code from the checkout CSS file.

    #checkout-payment-method-load .payment-method-content .actions-toolbar .primary .action.checkout {
      display: block;
    }
```

Finally, run the below Magento cmd to deploy static content again.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```